# FIM: Put connector space object in metaverse

Tags: microsoft-forefront

I am using Forefront Identity Manager and am new to it. I made a simple management Agent and imported some data in the connector space.

I used a "Full Import and Full Synchronisation" Run script.

How do I get that user objects in the metaverse?